# How to encode unicode strings to sequence like this "\xd1\x81" in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a string of unicode - `сентрября`
and i know this is expressed in the sequence like this:

```
\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd1\x8f
```

What is this type of expression encoded characters and how to convert any text from unicode to sequences like this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix "\x" indicates that it is hexadecimal. If the prefix is removed, you get the same output as with the "bin2hex" function in php.

I think this is the function you search for:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.bin2hex.php

```
bin2hex("сентрября") = d181d0b5d0bdd182d180d18fd0b1d180d18f
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are characters in [Windows-1252 (CP1252)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) some of them are special characters, so you can decode with [iconv function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php)

> `\x81` = `Ñ` (LATIN character)

```php
echo iconv("cp1252", "utf-8//IGNORE", "\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd1\x8f");
```

Result of the code Above: `ÐµÐ½Ñ‚ÑÑ€Ð±Ñ€Ñ`

**NOTE** this code is usually used for hack and inject code in your website.